# Duplicity gives InvalidBackendURL error when setting up Backblaze B2

Tags: backup, duplicity

When running Duplicity with Backblaze's B2 as outlined in [some articles](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001518354-How-to-configure-Backblaze-B2-with-Duplicity-on-Linux):

```
duplicity ~ b2://[keyID]:[application key]@[B2 bucket name]
```

Real values hidden, but provided though the Backblaze B2 UI.

I encounter the following error:

```
InvalidBackendURL: Syntax error (port) in: b2://[keyID]:[application key]@[B2 bucket name] AFalse BNone [keyID]:[application key partial]\
```

Where the application key is partially chopped off at the slash. I have attempted many alternatives to escape the slash such as double quotes, single quotes, and backslash escaping, but nothing improves the situation.

Answer (score 2):

as the target is given in url format

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

actually the proper solution would be to url-encode the userinfo, the part between schema:// and the @ . slash '/' for obvious reason is an illegal character there so it needs to be escaped which should be done via percent-encoding (url-encoding) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding . e.g.

```
duplicity ~ b2://keyID:application/key@[B2 bucket name]
```

would need to become

```
duplicity ~ b2://keyID:application%2Fkey@[B2 bucket name]
```

because **'/'** is **'%2F'** percent encoded.

have fun.. ede/duply.net

Comment: As user ede-duply.net replied, replace "/" in the applicationKey with "%2"

Comment: @overthehills wouldn't that be '%2F' ? just updated my answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The only resolution I have found is to create a new application key in the Backblaze B2 UI that does not include a slash. The creation of a new application key may need to be repeated several times to get one without a slash.